# java: how to make srollable panel with radio button and labels inside?

Tags: java, swing, jpanel

I got a JScrollPane in which I want to place a list of radio buttons and labels. My problem is the panel doesn't scroll, I suppose it's because i didn't set a viewport, but how can I set it when I have to many components?
My code looks something like this:

```
JScrollPane panel = new JScrollPane();
JRadioButton myRadio;
JLabel myLabel;
for(int i = 0; i<100; i++){
    myRadio = new JRadioButton();
    myLabel = new JLabel("text");
    panel.add(myRadio);
    panel.add(myLabel);
 }
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is better to put your buttons and labels in a wrapper `JPanel` and then drop that into a `JScrollPane`.

try this:

```
    JPanel panel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0,1));
    JRadioButton myRadio;
    for(int i = 0; i<100; i++){
        myRadio = new JRadioButton("text" + i);
        panel.add(myRadio);
     }
    JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(panel);
```

be sure to look into [ButtonGroup](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/ButtonGroup.html) as well.  ButtonGroups allow you to enforce the single selection constraint common to radio buttons.

Comment: I tried setting a JPanel as viewport but it doesn't work because it is not a component.

Comment: JPanel is most definitely a Component. Try the code above or "JScrollPane.setViewportView(myJPanel)".